# How to find keys from undefined schema

Tags: javascript, arrays, group

Suppose I have following array

```
array = [
 {
  optionA: "QA1",
  optionB: "QB1",
  optionC: "QC1",
  optionD: "QD1",
 },
 {
  optionA: "QA2",
  optionB: "QB2",
  optionC: "QC2",
  optionD: "QD2",
  optionE: "QD2",
 },
 {
  optionA: "QA3",
  optionB: "QB3",
 }
]
```

Expected output

```
tableHeader = {OptionA,OptionB,OptionC,OptionD,OptionE}
```

Wanted display questions data in a table format, which is not organised and has n number for options.

Comment: Tried all google searches and all JSON related websites, but not found on JSON keys grouping.

Comment: The expected format is incorrect. I'm assuming you need all keys as an array

Comment: yes correct, all keys as an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all keys as follows

```js
const array = [{optionA: "QA1",optionB: "QB1",optionC: "QC1",optionD: "QD1",},{optionA: "QA2",optionB: "QB2",optionC: "QC2",optionD: "QD2",optionE: "QD2",},{optionA: "QA3",optionB: "QB3",}]

const allKeys = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...array))
console.log(allKeys)
```

Comment: Apparently SO is a "get code for free site" +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```js
let header = new Set();
array.forEach((a) => {
  Object.keys(a).forEach((item) => {
    header.add(item);
  });
});
console.log(header);
```